# google app engine reverse key order query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google App Engine (GAE) GO version of a datastore query.  I want to get the list of keys in reverse order.  Forward order works, but when I add the hyphen to the order clause it fails.

q = q.Order("-__key__")

with the error:

Error: API error 4 (datastore_v3: NEED_INDEX): no matching index found.

Is this a bug? or not supported?

Comment: Are you running it on dev or live? For a search to work you need to have an index built. You can do this automatically by running the query on dev then deploying it.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported. `q.Order("__key__")` uses the `EntitiesByKind` index, which is ascending-only.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown#anc-indextables for details.