# API error 4 (datastore_v3: NEED_INDEX): no matching index found

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am currently attempting to upload a Guest Book application in Go that uses datastore for GAE found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-go/tree/part4-usingdatastore).

Running a GAE server from my computer using `goapp serve`, the application runs and works fine. I submitted two entries, and shut down the server. But, when uploaded immediately after using `goapp deploy -application xxx app.yaml`, I get `API error 4 (datastore_v3: NEED_INDEX): no matching index found.` on my URL. It has been about a day or so since I last served the files.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have the same index file: [`index.yaml`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-go/blob/part4-usingdatastore/index.yaml)?

Comment: Yes, [my folder](http://i.imgur.com/2TDVdpC.png).

Comment: You have the file, yes, but is its content equal to the one I [linked](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-go/blob/part4-usingdatastore/index.yaml)?

Comment: @icza sorry, it is the exact same. The files I am uploading have been downloaded directly from GitHub and have no changes.

Comment: The SDK may modify this file, so please check manually as it is not enough that you personally didn't modify it.

Comment: My answer to this question applies to your case as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250351/django-nonrel-query-confusion

Comment: The above comment by Dan should be posted more prominently as an answer to the  initial question.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove '.Order("-Date")' in [Line 41](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-go/blob/part4-usingdatastore/hello.go#L41), and try to deploy it again.

The reason is that q.Order("**key**") uses the EntitiesByKind index, which is not supported, see in [google-app-engine-reverse-key-order-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671090/google-app-engine-reverse-key-order-query)